# HBase Java Client: getMaster Connection refused

Tags: hbase

I have setup a single node with hadoop and hbase in pseudo distributed mode, of course zookeeper and the regionserver is also installed.

Everything runs smoothly but when it comes to connect to hbase via the Java Client API, I'm getting an exception.

I tried for hours to solve this problem, but I'm not able to.
I can telnet to remotemachine:60000, so it's not a port firewall problem.
The logs also don't report anything special.

(note from the logs debianhdfs is correctly set to the IP in the hostfile)

> 12/05/06 19:47:27 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection
>   to server debianhdfs/192.168.137.135:2181 12/05/06 19:47:27 INFO
>   zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to
>   debianhdfs/192.168.137.135:2181, initiating session 12/05/06 19:47:27
>   INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server
>   debianhdfs/192.168.137.135:2181, sessionid = 0x13721c707ff002f,
>   negotiated timeout = 40000 12/05/06 19:47:28 INFO
>   client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt
>   0 of 1 failed; no more retrying. java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused: no further information   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:408)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:328)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:883)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:750)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC$Invoker.invoke(HBaseRPC.java:257)
>     at $Proxy4.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:419)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:393)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:444)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:567)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.(HBaseAdmin.java:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:1296)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:57) Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: debianhdfs:60000
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.(HBaseAdmin.java:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:1296)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:57)

In standalone mode, non pseudo distributed I get the following exception with the same code:

> 12/05/06 20:32:49 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection
>   to server debianhdfs/192.168.137.135:2181 12/05/06 20:32:49 INFO
>   zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to
>   debianhdfs/192.168.137.135:2181, initiating session 12/05/06 20:32:49
>   INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server
>   debianhdfs/192.168.137.135:2181, sessionid = 0x1372210f8fe0004,
>   negotiated timeout = 40000 12/05/06 20:32:49 INFO
>   client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: ZooKeeper
>   available but no active master location found 12/05/06 20:32:49 INFO
>   client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt
>   0 of 1 failed; no more retrying.
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:564)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.(HBaseAdmin.java:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:1296)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:57) Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:601)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.(HBaseAdmin.java:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:1296)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:57)

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "debianhdfs"); 
        config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");    

    HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(config);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running in standalone, why not try to use the zookeeper that runs with HBase first? Since HBase manages its own local zookeeper when it is in standalone mode, using it might reduce the chances of meeting a bug, and will be easier for you to trouble shoot as you have less programs to manage.

To let HBase run its own ZK instance, head to `${HBASE_HOME}/conf/hbase-env.sh`, scroll all the way to the bottom and ensure there is a line `export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true`, or that the line is commented out (because by default HBase manages its own ZK)